# Mock dagger 2 modules while using factory

Tags: android, junit, mockito, dagger-2

I'm using android features with dagger 2.

My AppComponent looks as below:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {
    @Component.Factory
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Factory<MyApplication>
}
```

And my AppModule:

```
@Module(includes = [AndroidInjectionModule::class])
abstract class AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Binds
    @AppContext
    abstract fun provideContext(app: MyApplication): Context
}
```

I try to mock this and other modules (when they appear). I've read using `@Component.factory` is better than builder but I don't have idea how to mock it.

I tried to mock `SharedPreferences` as below but I think, I also have to provide mocked `Context`.

```
val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences::class.java)
val context: Context = Mockito.mock(Context::class.java)
Mockito.`when`(context.getSharedPreferences(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyInt())).thenReturn(sharedPrefs)

Mockito.`when`(sharedPrefs.getString(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(AuthType.UNDEFINED.toString())
```

How to mock `Context` and provide mocked `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 0):

Do not mock shared preferences or context. We know these android implementations work and they do not need to be tested.

Create a wrapping class that can be used as a mockable interface for your preferences to be unit tested.

```
class MyClassPreferences(context: Context) {

    val preferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("", MODE_PRIVATE)

    fun getPreferenceOne(): String {
        return preferences.getString(KEY, "")
    }

    fun setPreferenceOne(value: String) {
        preferences.edit().putString(KEY, value).commit()
    }

}
```

In test

```
Mockito.`when`(myClassPreferences.getPreferenceOne()).thenReturn("value")
```

Comment: It would be nice, if this class could be injected via dagger 2 as a service, could you provide an example?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Provide Context or SharedPreferences as injectable and annotate this class as Injectable or create a Provides for it. If this needs to be used as part of a service then Inject it at some stage within the Service's lifecycle.